# Tool for labeling audio

Tags: time-series, labels, audio-recognition

I have few thousand audio signals to label into 2 different classes and save them to numpy array for further training of models. MATLAB recently released `Signal Labeler` for their `Signal Analyzer`, that could help to label time series, but for certain reasons, I can't use it.

Is there any specific tool for analysis and labeling of time series for Python? It is not necessary to save data and labels into numpy arrays, `.csv` format or anything similar is suitable as well.

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) is a free and open source audio editing software, available for all common desktop operating systems. It can be used to annotate audio, by using Label Tracks. You can have a label at a certain position, or covering a selection of time.

### Annotating

1. Open or import your audio into Audacity
2. Select the audio track you want to annotate.
3. `Click Track` -> `Edit` -> `Labels` -> `Edit Labels` to add a new Label track
4. Select where in the track you want to annotate
5. Insert new label using keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + B`

Repeat until done with the track.

[image: Audacity with a label track]

### Export annotations

Export the labels using `File -> Export -> Export Labels`

### Loading annotations

To load the labels into Python, you can use this snippet of code:

```py
import pandas

path = 'PATH/TO/FILE'
labels = pandas.read_csv(path, sep='\t', header=None,
                        names=['start', 'end', 'annotation'],
                        dtype=dict(start=float,end=float,annotation=str))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll definitely try this!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: https://labelstud.io,
it is a free opensource tool via web browser with a good documentation and a lot of examples. Easy to start.

[image]

Or if you need a teamwork you can use the labeling platform: https://heartex.ai.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the ones below:

1. [audio-annotator](https://github.com/CrowdCurio/audio-annotator)

A JavaScript interface for annotating and labeling audio files.

[image]

2. [audio-labeler](https://github.com/hipstas/audio-labeler)

An in-browser app for labeling audio clips at random, using Docker and Flask.
[![enter image description here][4]]

3. [EchoML](https://github.com/ritazh/EchoML)

Play, visualize and annotate your audio files

[image]

4. [peak.js](https://github.com/bbc/peaks.js)

Browser-based audio waveform visualization and UI component for interacting with audio waveforms, developed by BBC UK.

[image]

5. [wavesurfer.js](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js)

Simple annotations tool, check the example.

[![enter image description here][10]]